# riverpod - consumer still observes after providerlistener

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm using a ProviderListener to handle single events and a consumer for changes in state.
Both observe the same `StateNotifierProvider`

So something like this...

```
ProviderListener(
        provider: authPP,
        onChange: (context, state) {
          // on change FOR SINGLE EVENT
        },
        child: Consumer(
          builder: (context, watcher, child) {
            //on state change
            //return watcher(authPP)..bla bla 
          },
        ))
```

Note: authPP is the same `stateNotifierProvider`

The tutorial I've watched on youtube seems to work fine observing the same `stateNotifierProvider`, however when I test its observed in `ProviderListener` and then in the consumer.

When really once something is observed in ProviderListener I want the Consumer to ignore it.

Should I be using two different `stateNotifierProvider` heres?

Thanks

Comment: You are telling both the `ProviderListener` and the `Consumer` to listen to the same provider, so they will always be listening. If you want them to listen differently, you should have them listen to different providers.

Comment: If you want to listen it once I recommend maybe wrapping it in a StatefulWidget and only using ProviderListener to do whatever logic you want, then just setState to update the child widget if you need it